Comma separated IP addresses in TShark output
I have a bunch of PCAP that I am dissecting programmatically using TShark. Some example bash code:
tshark -r my_pcap.pcap -2 -T fields -E separator=/t \
    -e frame.time_epoch \
    -e ip.src \
    -e ip.dst \
    -e frame.protocols \
    > my_output.tsv

Occasionally, I will get output where the ip.src and ip.dst fields have two IP addresses, separated by a comma (e.g., 192.168.19.1,192.168.10.10). I've got two questions:

What is happening to produce such an output? Are there specific situations in which this will occur?
Is there a best practice to handle this to ensure accurate information and/or retain maximum information?


To answer your first question:  There may be more than one source and destination IP address pairs due to such things as tunneling protocols, such as IP/GRE/IP, or certain ICMP error messages, such as "Destination Unreachable" messages, which, as stated in RFC792, include "The internet header plus the first 64 bits of the original datagram's data." in its payload.
I don't understand what you mean by your second question regarding best practices.

Is there a best practice for how to report on packets that contain this information? Specifically, given that I am trying to extract this information in an automated fashion, are there other fields from TShark that I should extract to ensure I have as complete of a picture as possible?

Best practice? I think it all depends on your use case.
By the way, you could even choose to ignore all but the first occurrences entirely if you want.  Using the current stable Wireshark release, 4.2.5, this is done with tshark -r my_pcap.pcap -2 -T fields -E separator=/t -E occurrence=f -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e frame.protocols, but with the most recent development release and eventual 4.4.0 release, you can also make use of the layer operator like so: tshark -r my_pcap.pcap -2 -T fields -E separator=/t -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.src#1 -e ip.dst#1 -e frame.protocols
